# Google Chrome Profiler : does the GC will take away my destroyed AngularJs Scopes?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, memory, garbage-collection, profiler

I have an angularJs application. Many "isolated" Scopes are created and when I don't need them anymore, I $destroy them and remove the elements from the page. That's fine.

With my Chrome Profiler, I have made a Heap Snapshot but the destroyed scopes still appear ! The active scopes (still usefull) appear with a yellow background **BUT, the destroyed ones appear with "no distance" and with white background.**
Does it means that they're fully-unlinked and the GC gonna take them away one day ?

[image: My Chrome Heap Snapshot]

Because if not, I will inspect my code to find why (and where) there are still linked...

Thanks for your help !

Damien

Answer (score 0):

You can track what holds them in the retainers view at the bottom.